How do i get around this permission error with tesseract-ocr
i am doing a python project, in which i use Tesseract-OCR. when i set it up from git, it gave me this error:
C:\Users\jpmv1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe C:\Users\jpmv1\Projects\tcc-zone\src\rpi\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpmv1\Projects\tcc-zone\src\rpi\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jpmv1\Projects\tcc-zone\src\rpi\main.py", line 13, in main
    placa = OCR_Plate()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jpmv1\Projects\tcc-zone\src\rpi\utils\ocr_utils.py", line 108, in OCR_Plate
    out = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng", config=config)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jpmv1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 486, in image_to_string
    return {
           ^
  File "C:\Users\jpmv1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 489, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jpmv1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 352, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpmv1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 275, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jpmv1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\jpmv1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado

Process finished with exit code 1

I already installed it with admin permissions and set up in my path...
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR'


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If Tesseract is already installed but not added to your PATH, it will likely cause this issue.
follow these steps:
Run the downloaded installer and follow the installation instructions. During installation, make sure to select the option to add Tesseract to your system PATH.
if you didnt do this, you can add it by locating the directory where Tesseract is installed. Typically, it is something like C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR. and adding it to the system variables, path
Verify Installation
Open a new command prompt. Type tesseract -v and press Enter. You should see the version information of Tesseract OCR if it is installed correctly.
Not sure how you installed Tesseract, but you can also get it from here:
Install and Find the Installation Path
Go to the Tesseract at UB Mannheim page https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki. Download the latest version of Tesseract for Windows

Tesseract is already in my path, but it seems that it only works if i run it in cmd as admin.
edit: even in admin, it doesnt work with python

Your pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd value is wrong - check the docs.
